# QMediaRecorder keeps recording theora/ogg

Tags: qt, qmediarecorder

No matter what QVideoSettings options I pass in, the resulting video file is appended a `.ogg` and the codec remains `theora`. I'm on ubuntu 17.04, running Qt5.9.1.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
QVideoEncoderSettings videoSettings;
videoSettings.setCodec("video/mpeg2"); // Can be anything
videoSettings.setResolution(640,480);
videoSettings.setFrameRate(30.0);
videoSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::VeryHighQuality);
videoSettings.setBitRate(500000);
videoSettings.setEncodingMode(QMultimedia::ConstantQualityEncoding);
m_VideoRecorder->setContainerFormat("video/x-matroska"); // Tried almost all other options
m_VideoRecorder->setVideoSettings(videoSettings);
```

This also happens on the included `camera` example...

Comment: See what codecs and containers are supported: `QMediaRecorder::supportedVideoCodecs()` and `QMediaRecorder::supportedContainers()`. You'll probably have to install some gstreamer or ffmpeg packages.

Comment: I have a huge list reported, for each of them but no matter which one I set it to it keeps producing ogg/theora.